# WIF: Custom Claims

Tags: wif, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm having a hard time understanding how a Claim should be defined.  There is a lot of information on the web about creating claims but none of it seems to agree.  I have found four attributes of a claim in different posts:

- ClaimType
- ClaimValue
- ValueType
- Right

Given a scenario where you want to create a claim the denotes a user has the right to edit a User object, what is the correct way to set these attributes?

Also, in WIF there doesn't seem to be a property for the "Right" attribute.  Is "Right" only used in the context of WCF?

Im confused, help!

EDIT:

Thanks for your responses. To make this a little more concrete, I am currently seeing two options for my custom claim:

1-ClaimType=Edit,ClaimValue=User

2-ClaimType=Action,ClaimValue=EditUser

Option one seems to be more "claims-based" and option to seems more "role-based".  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

There are two different `Claim` types in .Net. One in WIF (`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims`) and one in `System.IdentityModel.Claims` that was used in WCF pre-WIF (it's not really part of WCT though). Only the `System.IdentityModel.Claims.Claim` has a `Right` property as you mention.

I've used the claims approach with WCF and ASP.Net with and without WIF and the WIF programming model is definately the simpler of the two.

For the User editing scenario that you describe, I would define a role with a suitable name. UserEditor could be OK but it sounds very specific. You should look at the collection of all the permissions that you want to grant to those users and come up with a suitable summarising name (maybe UserAdministrator?).

For those users, you should add a role claim (i.e. of type http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role or `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role`). If your identity provider is external to your application and you can't control the claims it issues, then you will need to implement a custom `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` to transform the issued claim set by adding the new role claim.

Then you can decorate the operations you want to grant access to with a `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` something like this:

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "UserAdministrator")]

This framework is fairly flexible and can be used in a number of different ways in ASP.Net, WCF or just regular .Net development. Your question doesn't give a lot of context to allow a very specific answer with examples.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you read that claims should have a right property, I think that's misuse of the concept.

A set of claims on their own don't convey user rights. Rather:

claim set + **policy** = user rights.

Typically, claims based applications apply a policy to the set of incoming user claims to make authorization decisions. Role based access is the most common, so these decisions might be as simple as User.IsInRole("Manager"), which simply checks to see of the user has a claim of ClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" and ClaimValue="Manager".

An online liquor store might require users to be over the age of 21, in which case you check the age claim. However you would have a different policy for the Canadian version of this website, where the age limit might be 18. If such "rights" were communicated via the claims themselves, then this kind of policy flexibility wouldn't be possible.